# "Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric."

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a function that returns a table with a bunch of fields.
The query used in the function inserts data to a temp table which then inserts into the returning table.
query runs fine when I run it outside of the function but when I select from the function I get "Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric." error.

The structure for the returning table is the same is the table which selects and inserts into the returning table. Below is how the function is defined

```
ALTER  FUNCTION [dbo].[Func_PrescriberData](@NetworkID Bigint, @StartDate datetime, @EndDate datetime)

RETURNS  @rtnTable TABLE 
(
 Name nvarchar(1000) null,ClinicID int null ,NetworkPrescriberID int Null,GuideMedPatients int  NULL, InactivePatients int NULL,AvgAge decimal  NULL,AvgPHQScore decimal  NULL,
 [%RiskAssessmentHigh] varchar(10) NULL ,[%RiskAssessmentModerate] varchar(10)  NULL,[%RiskAssessmentLow] varchar(10)  NULL,
 ToxicologyTests int  NULL,[%ConsistentResults] varchar(10) NULL, [%Alcohol] varchar(10) NULL,[%NegativePrescribed] varchar(10) NULL
 ,[%Illicit] varchar(10)  NULL,TotalPDMPs int  NULL,[%AberrantResults] varchar(10)  NULL, CSAReviewed int  NULL,Type nvarchar(1000) null ,medlesstan15 int NULL,between15and59 int NULL,between60and100 int NULL,between101and500 int NULL,greaterthan500 int NULL, avgmed decimal NULL, [BH/AM] int NULL,OpiodsBelowThreshold int NULL,OpioidPreScreening int NULL,SedativesAntiAnxiety int NULL,Stimulants int NULL,Other int NULL) 
AS
BEGIN 
DECLARE @TempTable table
(
 Name nvarchar(1000) null,ClinicID int null ,NetworkPrescriberID int Null,GuideMedPatients int  NULL, InactivePatients int NULL,AvgAge decimal  NULL,AvgPHQScore decimal  NULL,
 [%RiskAssessmentHigh] varchar(10) NULL ,[%RiskAssessmentModerate] varchar(10)  NULL,[%RiskAssessmentLow] varchar(10)  NULL,
 ToxicologyTests int  NULL,[%ConsistentResults] varchar(10) NULL, [%Alcohol] varchar(10) NULL,[%NegativePrescribed] varchar(10) NULL
 ,[%Illicit] varchar(10)  NULL,TotalPDMPs int  NULL,[%AberrantResults] varchar(10)  NULL, CSAReviewed int  NULL,Type nvarchar(1000) null ,medlesstan15 int NULL,between15and59 int NULL,between60and100 int NULL,between101and500 int NULL,greaterthan500 int NULL, avgmed decimal NULL, [BH/AM] int NULL,OpiodsBelowThreshold int NULL,OpioidPreScreening int NULL,SedativesAntiAnxiety int NULL,Stimulants int NULL,Other int NULL) 
insert into @TempTable (
Name ,ClinicID,NetworkPrescriberID,GuideMedPatients, InactivePatients ,AvgAge ,AvgPHQScore ,[%RiskAssessmentHigh],[%RiskAssessmentModerate] ,[%RiskAssessmentLow]
 ,ToxicologyTests ,[%ConsistentResults], [%Alcohol] ,[%NegativePrescribed] ,[%Illicit],TotalPDMPs ,[%AberrantResults],
 CSAReviewed ,Type,medlesstan15,between15and59,between60and100,between101and500,greaterthan500,avgmed,[BH/AM],OpiodsBelowThreshold,OpioidPreScreening,SedativesAntiAnxiety,Stimulants,Other
```

It's probably hard to tell what the issue is from the above script but I'm looking for a way to debug where the issue is.
Strange thing is the function runs fine if I change one of the parameters (change NetworkID) which is supposed to return data in the same format.

Can someone help me point to where to look?

Thanks,

I've found a link to post the entire sql script. It can be found [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_sql_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMclFFaTZ2azVlMEk)

Comment: Please post an *entire* function that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Check all the columns that will be inserted into `decimal` column, I am guessing there is whitespace or special character from the original `varchar` column, which brings you that error

Comment: I would look in the part of the code that you aren't showing us for whatever reason.

Comment: @TabAlleman script is too long to post here

Comment: @AhmedMujtaba Then you might as well delete your question.  We can't find the error in the code you aren't showing us.

Comment: Okay I have updated my post witht the script link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check all the columns that will be inserted into `decimal` column, in your example that will be `AvgAge` and `AvgPHQScore`

I am guessing there is whitespace or special character from the original `nvarchar` column, which brings you that error.

The easiest way to check is to trying to locate which two columns are mapped to `AvgAge` and `AvgPHQScore` and then run the following statements to check whether all the values from the `nvarchar` column could be implicitly converted to `decimal`:

```
SELECT original_nvarchar_column
FROM TABLE
WHERE ISNUMERIC(original_nvarchar_column) = 0
```

If anything returns, that means not all the value from that `nvarchar` column could be converted to `decimal`, and which will result in the issue you got.

Comment: Thanks. I will try your suggestion